# How to stop SSRS report from splitting a line of text across pages?

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

At the bottom of my report, I have a signature line. It's a `TablixRow` which contains a `Rectangle` that is full size for the row. Inside that `Rectangle` is a series of `Textbox` objects.

The problem is that if the content of the report goes a bit long, that final line can be chopped right in the middle of the text, instead of the text beginning on the next page as you would expect. I can't imagine a single scenario where I would want this behavior. I need to make sure this never happens again.

I have tried fiddling with the `PageBreak` settings, like `BreakLocation` but that setting does nothing in this case.

How do I stop my SSRS report from splitting a line of text across pages?

Looks like this:

[image: chopped text]

Answer (score 0):

[it looks similar to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415627/ssrs-report-designer-cutting-off-column-chart-in-print-layout/73609519#73609519)
You can try to change size of the print page and orientation. press F4 on Design screen, you will see properties bar. There is a button (looks like a wierd spaceship or key) named "property pages".Paper size, orientation, mergins etc. can be set here.

Comment: I don't understand. The page must fit a physical piece of paper, and it does. The question is about keeping a line of text whole, something that all other printed document types just do by default.

Comment: sorry my mistake but your screenshot is not clear. I could think of 2 possible reasons 1 Maybe you didn't turn on the expandable feature of the area or text box you are using? 2Or is this line written in the footer (not the body)? As you know, the size of the footer is fixed.

Comment: It is not in the footer. In my question I state at the top "It's a TablixRow which contains a Rectangle that is full size for the row. Inside that Rectangle is a series of Textbox objects." I'm not sure what you mean by expandable feature.

Comment: at the tablix properties menu there is General section. On this section  "Page Break Options"  you may want to check those options

Comment: Yeah, I did. I also noted that in my question. Those settings have no effect.

Comment: i'll try it on my old project and write back to you as first thing monday