# SSRS Report Designer Cutting off Column Chart in Print Layout

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have a problem with my rdl report cutting off the column chart I put in when viewing it in print layout. The layout of the page is correct as no additional pages appear in the print layout.

I have a column chart that consists if 11 columns (categories) and it only seems to display 9 and half of the tenth off. It does not matter if I put the page orientation in landscape of portrait, the same problem exists. It also does not matter what size I make the chart, it seems to cut of the last column in print layout.

When I export the file to pdf then it works perfecty.

Can anyone assist me please?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change size of the print page and orientation. press F4 on Design screen, you will see properties bar. There is a button (looks like a wierd spaceship or key) named "property pages".Paper size, orientation, mergins etc. can be set here